# Extracting date components in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have problems with transforming a Pandas dataframe column with dates to a number.

```
    import matplotlib.dates
    import datetime
    for x in arsenalchelsea['Datum']:
       year = int(x[:4])
       month = int(x[5:7])
       day = int(x[8:10])
       hour = int(x[11:13])
       minute = int(x[14:16])
       sec = int(x[17:19])
       arsenalchelsea['floatdate']=date2num(datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec))
    arsenalchelsea
```

I want to make a new column in my dataframe with the dates in numbers, because i want to make a line graph later with the date on the x-as.

This is the format of the date:
2017-11-29 14:06:45

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: do you have sample data? you may also want to fix the indentation. This also seems like it may have been answered before here on SO based on the brief description.

Comment: the dataframe includes dates of the format: 2017-11-29 14:06:45

Comment: you're going to want to edit that into your question as well as show the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slicing strings to get date components is bad practice. You should convert to `datetime` and extract directly.

In this case, it seems you can just use `pd.to_datetime`, but below I also demonstrate how you can extract the various components once you have performed the conversion.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-01-15 14:55:42', '2017-11-10 12:15:21', '2017-12-05 22:05:45']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'sec']] = \
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month, x.day, x.hour, x.minute, x.second)).apply(pd.Series)
```

Result:

```
                 Date  year  month  day  hour  minute  sec
0 2017-01-15 14:55:42  2017      1   15    14      55   42
1 2017-11-10 12:15:21  2017     11   10    12      15   21
2 2017-12-05 22:05:45  2017     12    5    22       5   45
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i use those separate columns to make a line graph in matplotlib?